# Ad xmlns attributes in java

Tags: android, xml, xml-namespaces

I am currently converting an xml file to java coding, but I have met a problem. In my xml file I have a View with two xmlns attributes like this :

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.android.launcher"
```

How can I ad these to my custom FrameLayout in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `xmlns` attributes is to tell the design-time and build-time tools about the various UI elements such as `Button`, `TextView`, `FrameLayout` etc.

Simply importing the relevant widget and view classes if you're writing Java code to build the layout dynamically is basically the equivalent. In other words, don't worry about the `xmlns` attributes.

Comment: Then something else is the problem. Thanks for the answear.